# Detect screen width with CSS Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm guessing that because you can do this with Media Queries:

```
@media (min-width:500px) { … }
```

That at some point or another, the CSS stylesheet must know what width the screen is, sans Javascript.

Is this the case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62838844/12910765
this will help in finding current screen size for media query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`device-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width) which will test of the screen's width in px. That however is not entirely recommended. Use `max-width` and `min-width` (for the viewport) instead.

---

If you are trying to GET the screen width and use it (something like `content: (device-width);` of some sort, that's not possible. Stick with JavaScript.

**[Manual Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width)**

Answer (score 2):

As the client browser's viewport changes size, the browser will repaint the visible area. At that point in time the browser will be checking if there are media query styles that are relevant for the new viewport.

The CSS doesn't really know what width the browser's viewport is, so much as the browser knows what CSS is applicable for a specific viewport.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the detailed answer, so a CSS only solution to grab screen size is a no-no?

Comment: The benefit of media queries is that you can react to specific attributes of the viewport, so while you can't determine its exact size, you can adjust your content's representation by predicting and accounting for the viewport being within certain expected boundaries.

Comment: You may find http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/ to be an informative read.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm very familiar with Responsive Web Design and Media Queries, i was more thinking if i could leverage their power to grab screen size :)

Comment: That's not true. You have `device-width`

Comment: OH! So I've completely mis-interpreted the question when he said `know what width the screen is` as the size of the browser window. Yes, you're completely correct Rikudo.

Comment: Or maybe I misinterpreted the answer? Now I'm confused :X

Answer (score 2):

Well...

```
@media(width:1024px){
  p#id:after{
    content:"1024px";
  }
}
```

If the width of the viewport is 1024 pixels, this displays the text "1024px" after the designated <p> element. You could (hypothetically) put several thousands of such blocks of CSS to display the width of the viewport, for any reasonable value of its width. (Note that the text isn't selectable in some browsers.)

The more you know... (please don't actually do this)

Answer (score 1):

In html ->

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

OR

In CSS ->

```css
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
  }
```

Hope it helped.