# Use device-width in CSS? JS possibilities?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, css

Is there any way to reference device-height and device-width in your CSS in order to center a div containing dynamic content of varying sizes (images)? Is it possible to use JS to get the effective viewport dimensions and then reference them with SASS/LESS, or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to get the viewport with JavaScript:
http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/

But I would suggest looking into CSS Media Queries:
[Detect screen width with CSS Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050696/detect-screen-width-with-css-media-queries)