# Shouldn't window.screenX and window.screenY work on browsers on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, cross-browser

When I log `window.screenX` on my desktop Chrome, I see the value `1920`

When I do the same on my phone and iPad both on Safari and Mobile I either see `0` or some really weird values.

**From MDN** [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX):

[image]

**QUESTION**

Isn't that supposed to work on both desktop and mobile, devices and browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What information are you actually trying to return? From your MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX):

> **Returns:**
>
> A number equal to the number of CSS pixels from the left edge of the browser viewport to the  left edge of the screen.

Do you have your browser in a windowed mode on your mobile devices? Because in a full screen mode, like most mobile device browsers remain in, it should always return `0` because there are no pixels between the left hand side of the device's screen and the start of the browser window.

Are you actually trying to measure the space between the left side of the screen and the start of the browser viewport, or are you really trying to get the horizontal resolution of the entire screen? If it is the latter, what you are looking for may be the `window.screen.width` property. The documentation for that property can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) on MDN.

Comment: You are right. Totally misread that. I'm insanely trying to figure out a way to get the viewport size regardless of the zoom level and I though `screenX` would help me. I thought it would give me screen dimensions instead of browser window dimensions, but that's not the case at all, as you correctly pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I'm seeing 1920 on my PC because I have two monitors, and Chrome browser is currently positioned full screen in the right one.

Comment: Yes, I know  I already assumed that was the reason. Thanks for confirming it for me though! Glad I could help. Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Do you know if `window.screen.width` is displayed in CSS pixels or actual screen pixels? From my tests, it seems CSS pixels, although I was expecting actual screen pixels, because of the API name `screen`. I don't see the info in the DOCs. Do you know that?

Comment: I am about 95% sure it is returning CSS pixels. The property is specified under the CSSOM (CSS Object Model) ([specification here](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-screen-width)) so I think that is a good hint it is CSS pixels. Also, in this other [SO thread about media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095742/how-is-the-screen-size-measured-for-media-queries), a comment says it is CSS pixels.

Comment: On my laptop if I have my resolution at 2560x1440 and run screen.width it gives me 2560, but if I change my OS resolution zoom to the recommended 150% it returns 1707. Seems like CSS pixels to me.

Comment: Yeah, from my tests it seems to be in CSS pixels. Good news! I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721344/are-window-screen-width-and-height-returned-values-in-css-pixels-or-actual-scree) about this. Thanks