# Are window.screen.width and height returned values in CSS pixels or actual screen pixels?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, cross-browser, pixel

From the API name `screen` and from this DOC link, I **would expect them to be actual screen size pixels.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width

[image]

But from the tests I've run so far, **it seems they return CSS pixels.**

- `360` for `window.screen.width` for my Galaxy A5 (both on Chrome and Firefox)
- `768` for `window.screen.width` for my iPad (both on Chrome and Safari)

Which are CSS pixel values.

**QUESTION**

Is this consistent across browsers? Can I trust I'll always get CSS pixel values?

Comment: It is screen resolution for width and height and it is in pixel  see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp  we need to send feedback to  Mozilla community

Comment: Please read this article about all "sizes" https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/ . There are some sizes that will not give the correct result.

Comment: @AlanM Your comment does not answer OPs question, he is asking whether it is returning normal pixels or CSS pixels. Further, w3schools is a poor source of information as much of what is there is incomplete, outdated, or flat out wrong.

Comment: @bron, thanks! But that doesn't answer the question. They say "device size" but they don't mention if the size is in CSS pixels or actual resolution pixels. I think they're CSS pixels, but the API name is really misleading in this case, IMO. Thanks.

Comment: @cbdeveloper. They will give CSS pixel values like @media(...) width and height. The (old) article I mentioned is to give you an idea what is best to use in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the confirmation that it is in CSS pixels in the CSS spec.

https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-screen-width

[image]